# using AccountContactRelation in apex

Tags: apex, accountcontactrelation

I want to use AccountContactRelation in Apex but get an error message when I try to run the code. For example when I try to run this code on Workbench:

```
AccountContactRelation[] ACRs = new list<AccountContactRelation>();
for(AccountContactRelation acr : ACRs) {
   if(acr.Id == null) {continue;}
}
```

I get the error message "COMPILE ERROR: Variable does not exist: Id".

** 'Contacts to Multiple Accounts Settings' is allowed on my org and I'm working with API 43.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: I executed the same code in dev console and workbench without editing. Its working fine for me.

Comment: Are you sure, this is the exact code that you are executing?